# jdbc-mysql what happens to the value of "'+variable+'" if variable is null?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, null

I got the following string

```
"SELECT song_title,artist FROM SONG WHERE SONG_TITLE='"+title+"' AND ARTIST='"+artist+"' ";
```

what is the value of '"+artist+"' if the string artist is null? Is'"+artist+"' null?

Comment: No,  '"+artist+"' = empty string, beacuse you add `' '` between variable.

Answer (score 1):

It will create a string that looks, as I am sure you can guess:

```
SELECT song_title,artist FROM SONG WHERE SONG_TITLE='Uptown Funk You Up' AND ARTIST=''
```

So the search will only find songs that have the title 'Uptown Funk You Up' where the artist is blank or NULL.  It will not find a row in your database if you one have one record where the title is 'Uptown Funk You Up' and the artist is "Mark Ronson".

If that was not your intention, then you need to use an OR logical compare or some additional logic before or while creating the query.  Test for title or artist being an empty string, and change your query (psuedo code below, not PHP saavy)

```
query = "SELECT song_title,artist FROM SONG WHERE "
if title != "" then
    query += "title='"+title+"'"

if artist != "" then
    query += " AND artist='"+artist+"'"

results = mySQL(query)
```

That make sense?  Does this help?

Comment: actually i just wanted to see if there was a row meeting those requirements because (title,artist) is unique. However select returned no rows even if there were rows with the exact title and artist=null...Thanks for the feedback though

Comment: I think I understand what you are looking for.  In your original search, if either value is NULL, then it will return zero matches, especially if in your DB table, there are no rows where artist and title are ever empty.  So technically, you search does exactly what you want it to do.  More specifically to answer your original question more clearly, since the value of artist is NULL or empty, then nothing will be placed in between the quotes and the query will look for a row where artist is empty.  Combine that with the AND logic, the row must have an empty artist and a title that matches.

Comment: One word of warning.. NULL and empty string are not always the same, especially in the actual query.  However, when using a programmatic approach, how PHP, Perl, Python, etc.. all interpret a NULL value is different, make no assumptions, test your logic.